# c# - Opening a Chrome browser zoomed in?

Tags: c#

I am using `Process.Start("chrome")` to launch a Chrome window. Is there a property I can include to have the page launch zoomed in a certain amount?

Comment: Maybe you could send the Ctrl+'+' command to the process. That would zoom it in.

Answer (score 3):

Use Process arguments --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 to start Chrome

```
Process.Start("chrome", "--force-device-scale-factor=1.5")
```

This feature is still in experimental only. So if it doesn't work, you can either try changing first `--` to `/` or try switching on experimental mode in Chrome.

**Documentation**

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/display/display_switches.cc?q=kForceDeviceScaleFactor&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=31